# pythreejs fails to render large mesh in jupyter notebook (but succeeds at rendering a small one)

Tags: python, three.js, jupyter-notebook, mesh

I've been attempting to use pythreejs to render 3D objects in my jupyter notebooks. For a first test, I did the following simple example with a tetrahedron:

```py
# Plot a mesh with pythreejs
import pythreejs as p3js
from IPython.display import display

vertices = [[0.3,0,0],[0,0.5,0.4],[-0.2,0.3,-0.1],[0.9,0,-0.3]]
faces = [[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,0,3],[0,1,3]]
colors = ['#ff0000','#00ff00','#0000ff','#ffffff']

faces = [f + [None, [colors[i] for i in f]] for f in faces]

geo = p3js.Geometry(vertices=vertices, faces=faces, colors=colors)
geo.exec_three_obj_method('computeFaceNormals')
mesh = p3js.Mesh(
   geometry=geo,
   material=p3js.MeshBasicMaterial(vertexColors='VertexColors',
                                   side='DoubleSide'),
   position=list(-np.mean(vertices, axis=0)))
cam = p3js.PerspectiveCamera(position=[4,0,0], up=[0,0,1], fov=10)
scene = p3js.Scene(
    children=[mesh, cam, p3js.AmbientLight(color=u'0x777777')],
    background='black')
renderer = p3js.Renderer(camera=cam, scene=scene,
                         controls=[p3js.OrbitControls(controlling=cam)])
display(renderer)
```

When I evaluate the above in a jupyter notebook (Python 3.6.6, pythreejs version 1.1.0), I get more-or-less what I expect: a black background with a funny-looking tetrahedron whose vertices have different colors. Great! So I try a more complicated mesh. I've uploaded the data for this mesh in gzipped-hdf5 format to file dropper, [here](http://www.filedropper.com/100610hdf5); you can download it, gunzip it, then read it with the following code:

```py
# load the mesh
import h5py
with h5py.File(downloaded_filename, 'r') as f:
    vertices = [list(xyz)         for xyz in f['vertices']]
    faces    = [list(ijk)         for ijk in f['faces']]
    colors   = [s.decode('utf-8') for s   in f['colors']]
```

I have verified the mesh data with plenty of other software, so I do not believe that the mesh itself is the problem (though the mesh might have a few minor defects--e.g., two vertices that are actually at the same position). When I use the h5py-loading code to replace the `vertices = ...`, `faces = ...`, and `colors = ...` lines my earlier code-block, I instead get a blank black box. Note also that `mesh`, when evaluated by itself, shows a blank box as well (though in the case of the tetrahedron, it showed a rendering of the mesh). I haven't seen anything in the documentation that would suggest that large meshes wouldn't work. Is something else wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: The original file was too large for file-dropper so I uploaded a new one (same file, just gzipped now).

Comment: Unfortunately, the link for downloading the mesh does not work for me. It just redirects me to www.filedropper.com .

Comment: Is the kernel still busy? Might just be a large processing task...

Comment: My mistake: the file was apparently too large; now re-uploaded the same file, just gzipped. @J. Blackadar the kernel is definitely not busy; it displays the black window and continues to work, but nothing ever appears in the black display region.

Comment: Maybe it's a camera location/angle issue. Did you try to play with that?

Comment: I don't think it's a camera issue; I played with those settings a lot, but if you can get the mesh to display with the provided code/data and some camera movements, let me know.